# Is there a way to get how long an activity has been running for in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, spotify

I am looking for a function to tell me when a user's activity started.

I have tried the created_at function of the Spotify import but it only gives the time when the current song started. I am looking for something that tells me when the activity started.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`timestamps`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Activity.timestamps) field on an Activity:

> A dictionary of timestamps. It contains the following optional keys:
>
> - start: Corresponds to when the user started doing the activity in milliseconds since Unix epoch.
> - end: Corresponds to when the user will finish doing the activity in milliseconds since Unix epoch.
>
> ##### Type:
>
> dict

Comment: How would I use that? I currently use the following but it does not work: discord.Activity.start